# Wordpress is_home() not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make background color on homepage is transparent and on otherpage background is blue. 
[image]
I have using is_home() function but can't work. This is my code

```
<?php
        if(is_home()){
            // we are on the home page
            echo '<header id="masthead" class="site-hulu" role="banner">';
        }else {
            echo '<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">';
        }
    ?>
```

How to fix its guys? Thanks before for your helping

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using is_front_page() instead

See here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home specifically

> Blog Posts Index vs. Site Front Page 
>   Since WordPress 2.1, when the static front page functionality was introduced, the blog posts index and site front page have been treated as two different query contexts, with is_home() applying to the blog posts index, and is_front_page() applying to the site front page.

Comment: I was using is_front_page(), I got blank interface.

Comment: A completely blank page sounds like a syntax error more than a function error to me. Are you sure the code was OK?

Comment: Yes I think it's ok sir, my homepage is static page 
'<?php
        if(is_front_page()){
            // we are on the home page
            echo '<header id="masthead" class="site-hulu" role="banner">';
        }else {
            echo '<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">';
        }
    ?>' 
and if I run again I got blank page